# Fiware Orion: time based notifications

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

How to make time based notifications with Orion?
Say I want to send the value of an entity every day at noon.

It seems that the functionality has been deprecated: http://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/deprecated/

I use Orion notification service to trigger the sending of SMS with an external service (Plivo). So I cannot perform a query instead as recommended in the deprecation notice.

If it's not feasible in Orion, what complementary module do you recommend?

Comment: Why not do your application, that would receive notifications, request periodically the data you are interested in? It is the given recommendation in the documentation: " they aren't really needed, as any use case based on ONTIMEINTERVAL notification can be converted to an equivalent use case in which the receptor runs queryContext at the same frequency (and taking advantage of the features of queryContext, such as pagination or filtering)."

Comment: @Dalton yes it's possible, I just wanted to avoid developing an application for that. Also to avoid having the configure the payload in two different places: Orion for regular notifications, and my application for time based notifications.

Comment: If you opt by what is suggested, it will not needed to create notifications and, thus, you will need to configure payload only in the request...

Comment: @Dalton as a workaround is it possible to create a subscription in Orion based on the attribute of an entity; and to have a process changing the attribute at fixed times? That should trigger the notification at fixed times. For example have an entity "MyAlert" with an attribute "triggerAlert".

Comment: It is possible your `MyAlert` entity just change its attribute `triggerAlert` periodically, at fixed times. Your entity application has to control this. Thus, the notifications will work as you are expecting. This is another approach different from the other I proposed before and it also works. :)

Comment: I had another idea... Can I setup the field `throttling` in my notification to get the notification once a day? `Throttling` sets the maximum frequency of notification, so setting it to 86400 should send the message once a day. Of course provided that something changed in the entities selected.

Comment: Yes. You can do this way. In this case, it does not matter how many times the attribute value will change, because just one notification a day will be sent.